# All continuous maps $f:M\to S^1$ are null-homotopic, is $M$ simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups

Suppose that $M$ is a connected topological manifold so that $M$ is path connected, locally path connected and locally connected. Suppose we know that for all continuous maps $f:M\to S^1$ we know that $f_*:\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(S^1)$ is the trivial map. I have shown that this is equivalent to all continuous functions $f:M\to S^1$ being null-homotopic. Is it possible that this also implies that $M$ is simply connected?

If $M$ is simply connected, then $\pi_1(M) = 0$ implies that $f_* = 0$ for all continuous $f$. But it is not clear to me that a converse should hold. That is $f_* = 0$ for all continuous functions $f:M\to S^1$ implies that $\pi_1(M) = 0$.

Comment: "Locally connected" is redundant if you impose "locally path connected", which is itself redundant if you impose "topological manifold". Moreover, "connected + locally path connected" is equivalent to "path connected + locally path connected". Putting all together, the portion of the first sentence after "connected topological manifold" is redundant.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I am aware they are redundant. I am just unsure which condition might be relevant.

Comment: this is equivalent to asking if all group homomorphisms $G \to \mathbb Z$ are trivial, then is $G$ trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a method for basically constructing all counterexamples.

A continuous map $f : M \to S^1$ is homotopic to a constant if and only if the induced fundamental group homomorphism $f_* : \pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$ is trivial. Furthermore, every homomorphism $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ is the induced homomorphism of a continuous function $M \to S^1$. These two facts are guaranteed by applying the fact that $S^1$ has contractible universal cover; in other words, $S^1$ is an [Eilenberg-MacClane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space), specifically $S^1=K(\mathbb Z,1)$.

It follows that $M$ satisfies the property

> All continuous maps $M \mapsto S^1$ are homotopic to a constant

if and only if every homomorphism $\pi_1(M) \to \mathbb Z$ is trivial, which holds if and only if every homomorphism $H_1(M) \to \mathbb Z$ is trivial. Assuming in addition that $M$ is compact --- and hence $H_1(M)$ is a finitely generated abelian group --- this holds if and only if $H_1(M)$ is finite.

But, there are lots of finitely generated groups with nontrivial, finite abelianization, and each of them can be realized as the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ of some compact manifold $M$, in which case $\text{ab}(\pi_1(M)) \approx H_1(M)$ has no homomorphisms to $\mathbb Z$. And yet in this case $\pi_1(M)$ is nontrivial, so $M$ is not simply connected.

Answer (score 10):

$\mathbb{RP}^2$ is connected, path connected, and not simply connected, but since $f_*:\pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$ is a group homomorphism it means that $f_*:\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ must be the trivial map. Since $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.